# Query JSON array using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to get the data within the `Rule` column.  It has a value in JSON format.  I'm trying to construct the query to get the part which says `"value":8`.

Column name: `Rule`.

JSON within column:

```
{"element":[{"maxDiscount":0,"minAmount":100,"total":{"type":"ABSOLUTE_OFF","value":8}}]}
```

I'm stuck with this query:

```
select id, rule->>'$."total"' from table A
order by id desc;
```

My desired output is...

```
ID | Value
1A | 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the JSON path `$.element[0].total.value` here:

```
SELECT
    id,
    JSON_EXTRACT(rule, '$.element[0].total.value') AS val
FROM tableA
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
rule ->> "$.element[0].total.value"
```

This gives you the `value` attribute for the `total` entity that is the first element in the `element` array.

This can also be expressed:

```
json_extract(rule, "$.element[0].total.value")
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a2247b104de19a7d60955a1bcf83e77)**:

```
select rule ->> "$.element[0].total.value" res
from (
    select cast('{"element":[{"maxDiscount":0,"minAmount":100,"total":{"type":"ABSOLUTE_OFF","value":8}}]}' as json) rule
) t
```

```
| res |
| :-- |
| 8   |
```